# VueJS - How to send a POST request of a JSON array each including data in addition to a File or Picture for each array element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to send through Axios to PHP formData from a dynamic Form where a user can add as many "persons" as he wants.
Each person has data + a picture.

Here's the data format

```
data: {
    person:{
        personname: '',
        securitynumber: '',
        dob: '',
        picture: '',
    },
    persons: [],
},
```

Everything works without the picture, I'm able to upload images by creating a FormData, but how is it possible to change the whole data array (persons) to JSON with each element having its own picture file.

On submit i'm appending to the formData

```
 var formData = new FormData();

        Object.keys(this.persons).forEach(key => {
            formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(this.persons[key]));
        });
```

However, i'm having trouble adding a file(picture) specifically to each person item in the array.
(fetching it from the form input with ref and having it be part of the form data JSON).

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: I didn't implement the "picture per person" yet, as i don't know how to approach it, i'm trying to handle the file upload and to assign each file to a person (inside each array element), but I didn't get to a working solution yet).
loading 1 file is easy, loading 1 file for each person in 1 array to be converted to formData to be posted is more complex and i didn't get to a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by ditching the ref idea and working with an onChange that takes the elements as such:

In the form loop :

```
<input class="form-control-file" :id="'file-'+index" type="file" accept="image/*"
                                               @change="onFileChange(person, $event)">
```

Vues function:

```
onFileChange(item, e) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(item, files[0]);
    },
    createImage(item, file) {
        var image = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e) => {
            item.image = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
```

That way, for every form element (vue array element), i'm able to assign an image.
The result is a formData that includes all the array elements easily posted to PHP.